# Value binding between template and controller

Tags: ember.js

I built a small ember app, but I cannot access the controllers model from the template.

how can I fix this JSbin to get the data to display

http://jsbin.com/eniMUGe/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some javascript weirdness. It seems that when you break the line in the return statement, undefined is returned. Using `return array` in the same line works.

```
Demo.RouteaRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
      return [{
          title:'hello' 
        },
         {
          title:'worldy' 
        },
         {
          title:'world' 
        } 
      ];

    }
});
```

Give a look in the jsbin http://jsbin.com/usaRIZo/1/edit

Comment: ye makes sense that it returns undefined, couldn't see the issue though